# How to use ALAssetLibrary to get Local Photos in Camera Roll

Tags: ios, camera, photo, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                           usingBlock:libraryGroupsEnumeration 
                         failureBlock:failureblock];
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock groupEnumerAtion = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
        if (result!=NULL) {

            if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {

                [self._dataArray addObject:result];
            }

        }
    };

ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock
    libraryGroupsEnumeration = ^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop){
        //within the group enumeration block.filter to enumerate just photos.
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        if (group!=nil) {
            NSString *g=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",group];
            NSLog(@"gg:%@",g);//gg:ALAssetsGroup - Name:Camera Roll, Type:Saved Photos, Assets count:71
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:groupEnumerAtion];
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                [self saveToDB:self._dataArray];

            });
        }

    };
```

Assume that my Camera Roll have 100 photos,and I want get first 30 to save to my database.but in above code ,I must wait for 100 results fisishing.After 30 write to database , continue to get another 30 until end.
because get 100 or even more photos will delay my UI refresh.It looks not comfortable.
Thanks a lot!

what should I write.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
if (result!=NULL) {

    if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])         {

          [self._dataArray addObject:result];

            if([self._dataArray count] == 30){

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

                 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self._dataArray]; //please change the array declaration to top of this method. Because the Block will not allow to do it here.               
                 [self._dataArray removeAllObjects];
                 [self saveToDB:array];
                 //array release,if not using ARC

           });
       }
    }

}
```

and

```
if (group!=nil) {

            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:groupEnumerAtion];
        }
        else if([self._dataArray count] > 0) {

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

                    [self saveToDB:self._dataArray];

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try saving to the database on a background thread, and let CoreData (assuming you use CoreData) update the NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread by handling NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.

You could still save after 30 photos, that might relieve some of the I/O stress, but you'd have to test performance.